# Showing generic class eg Table<String> in xml comments in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, comments

I know this maybe a basic question but I just can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I have a class like this

```
Table<T>
{}
```

then I have some code that uses the above class that I would like to comment I would like to be able to do something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// blah blah blah Table<String>
/// </summary>
```

But I can't use the angle bracket in the comment as it thinks it's a tag and when the help shows up it just has an error about no end tag for .

How do I show generic classes in comments in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use XML entities (sort of escape sequences): &lt; for < and &gt; for >. Intellisense will display < as  and > correctly.

**EDIT**: Here's a cheat sheet listing of all of the XML entities:

```
&lt;   for <
&gt;   for >
&amp;  for &
&quot; for "
&apos; for '
```

Answer (score 2):

try using an &lt; instead of a <

Answer (score 1):

The problem with &lt; is that it looks ugly and is hard to read in comments. I use the following: `GenericThing≪T,U≫`. That's not two angle bracket characters but a single character. It looks OK in Intellisense and when reading the comments. If you use <summary> etc to output documentation then it's not strictly correct, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you place it in a `cref` element, you can instead use `{` and `}`.
That is, inside the summary, instead of `Table<string>`, you put `<cref="Table{string}"/>`

From [XML Documentation Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments):

> To refer to generic identifiers in code reference ... As a special case, the compiler parses the braces [in `crefs`] as angle brackets to make the documentation comment less cumbersome to author when referring to generic identifiers.

For more info about `cref`, see [cref Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/cref-attribute):

> The `cref` attribute in an XML documentation tag means "code reference." It specifies that the inner text of the tag is a code element, such as a type, method, or property. Documentation tools like DocFX and Sandcastle use the cref attributes to automatically generate hyperlinks to the page where the type or member is documented.

---

NOTE: For convenience, I sometimes use `{}` instead of `<>` (in a summary comment) even if NOT part of a `cref`.