# Xml string in a C# summary comment

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm documenting a few methods I wrote in C# that deal with parsing tokens. Due to some technical restraints in other areas of the system, these tokens need to take the form of XML elements (i.e., `<tokenName />`). I'd like to put the format of those tokens in the summary statement itself.

However, this throws an error: Badly formed XML -- A name was started with an invalid character". Is there any sort of escape character sequence I can use to embed XML in my C# summary comments?

Comment: See also [Can use "{}" inside cref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43474585/199364). A bit more detail on that in [If you place it in a cref element, you can instead use { and }](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55307764/199364).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape characters in c# comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377372/how-do-i-escape-characters-in-c-sharp-comments)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use standard XML escaping. For example:

```xml
<summary>This takes a &lt;token1&gt; and turns it into a &lt;token2&gt;</summary>
```

It's not super-easy to type or read as code, but IntelliSense properly unescapes this and you see the right, readable thing in the tooltip.

Answer (score 30):

Use a CDATA section. For example:

```xml
<![CDATA[ <name>Bob</name> ]]>
```

This is more elegant and readable in source than encoding special characters in entity references when you have a larger XML piece.

If the XML you want to embed itself contains CDATA sections, you need to use multiple CDATA sections as described in [another answer on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/a/223782/2157640) or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting). Or you can always use plain entity references as described in other answers here.

Comment: But see [VisualStudio's tooltip doesn't display anything inside a CDATA-section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8572910/199364).

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem. Using `<![CDATA[]]>` will hide the comment in IntelliSense.

Replacing both `<` and `>` was too much work for me (lazy :) ). I found out that just replacing the `<` with `&lt;` was enough for IntelliSense because it makes the xml invalid and suitable for IntelliSense to parse as text in your summary block.

Here is an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parse the queue process response
/// <para>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>&lt;result success="True">&lt;entity type="resource" operation="update" />&lt;/result></para>
/// <![CDATA[
/// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><result success="True"><entity type="resource" operation="update" /></result>
/// ]]></summary>
/// <param name="response"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

IntelliSense will show this:

```
Parse the queue process response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><result success="True"><entity type="resource" operation="update" /></result>
```

Answer (score 7):

I use escape-sequences, because VisualStudios tooltip doesn't display anything that's inside a CDATA-section.