# How do I include an html tag in a C# summary so that it is processed as text (not parsed as XML)?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, summary

I'm writing an HTML parser in C# and want to include examples of the HTML that it handles in the summary XML blocks.   How do I prevent the < and > characters from messing up the auto-documentation of Visual Studio 2008?

example:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a FlowSegment based on an HTML code, i.e. <bold>
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="code"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public FlowSegment(string code)
  {
```

Unfortunately the  example causes the tool tip for this constructor to display (in part):

```
XML comment includes invalid XML
```

instead of the summary comment.

How can I escape the < and > characters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best solution I found was to change it so as to replace < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`

as found in the [XML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

That makes the example look as follows:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a FlowSegment based on an HTML code, i.e. &lt;bold&gt;
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="code"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public FlowSegment(string code)
  {
```

Which makes the desired tool-tip display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate with:
[Xml string in a C# summary comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607094/xml-string-in-a-c-sharp-summary-comment)

An alternative solution is also to use `CDATA`:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a FlowSegment based on an HTML code, i.e. <![CDATA[ <bold> ]]>
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="code"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public FlowSegment(string code)
  {
```