# How do I escape characters in C# comments?

Tags: c#

I realized today that I don't know how to escape characters in comments for C#. I want to document a generic C# class, but I cannot write a proper example since I don't know how to escape the `<` and `>` characters. Do I have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`? I don't like if that is the case since I want to make it easy to read the comment in the actual document so I don't have to generate some kind of code document to be able to read the example code.

Comment: Could you show an example comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xml string in a C# summary comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607094/xml-string-in-a-c-summary-comment)

Comment: @Mark: You're right, but it's not only XML... I was trying to write an example for generics which is not XML but it uses '<' and '>'. But the solution is the same for both.

Comment: The greater-than symbol doesn't need to be escaped, and for the less-than symbol you can paste this slight variation: ⋖

Answer (score 187, accepted):

If you need to escape characters in XML comments, you need to use the character entities, so `<` would need to be escaped as `&lt;`, as in your question.

The alternative to escaping is using `CDATA` sections, to the same effect.

As you noted, this would produce good looking documentation, but a horrible comment to read...

Comment: Just for reference `<` would be `&lt;` and `>` would be `&gt;`.  As an example, `List&lt;string&gt; myStringList = new List&lt;string&gt;();`

Comment: @ArvoBowen Just in case someone's missing the obvious, `lt`/`gt` stand for “less than”/“greater than”, respectively.

Comment: Interestingly, only `<` needs to get escaped with `&lt;`, `>` can stay as it is: `List&lt;string> myStringList = new List&lt;string>();`. At least this works in intellisense. Strangely enough, `CDATA`  does not work in intellisense. I didn't check how it looks in auto-generated docs.

Comment: Can confirm that  VS 2013 does not render `CDATA` in intellisense. `&lt;` makes the comment hard to read.

Answer (score 74):

In plain C# comments you can use any character (except `*/` if you started the comment with `/*`, or the newline character if you started the comment with `//`). If you are using XML comments then you can use a [CDATA section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076.aspx) to include '<' and '>' characters.

See [this MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/11/750056.aspx) for more information on XML comments in C#.

---

For example

```
/// <summary>
/// Here is how to use the class: <![CDATA[ <test>Data</test> ]]>
/// </summary>
```

Comment: You're probably correct if you want to genereate nice looking html-documents, but I'm more interesting about getting the intellisense tips in VS correct, and for that it seems that I have to use XML escaping. But +1 for the alternative.

Comment: Hmm, illegible machine garbage in my comments only help if we take the time to build our document file when the vast, vast, vast (did I mention vast?) majority of use cases is reading the comments in the source (preferably an interface).

Comment: In VS2022, using CDATA in the XML comments highlights them in a different color and makes them very readable. A great way to include a code sample in the comment. Meanwhile intellisense strips the CDATA markup and shows the raw content. For example if my comment was "Use it like this: <![CDATA[ MyType<T> t = new MyType<T>(); ]]>" then it looks like this in intellisense: "Use it like this: MyType<T> t = new MyType<T>();

Answer (score 24):

You said "I want to make it easy to read the comment in the actual document".  I agree.

Developers spend most of their lives *in the code*, not perusing auto-generated docs.  Those are great for thirdparty libraries like charting, but not for in-house development where we work with all of the code.  I'm sort of shocked that MSFT hasn't come up with a solution that supports developers better here.  We have regions that dynamically expand/collapse code...why can't we have an in-place comment rendering toggle (between raw text and processed XML comment or between raw text and processed HTML comment)?.  Seems like I should have some elementary HTML capabilities in my method/class prologue comments (red text, italics, etc). Surely an IDE could work a little HTML processing magic to liven up inline comments.

**My hack-of-a-solution solution**:  I change '<' to "{" and '>" to "}".  That seems to cover me for the typical example usage style comment, including your specific example.  Imperfect, but pragmatic given the readability issue (and problems with IDE comment coloring that ensue when using '<')

Comment: Your "hack of a solution" seems to be more correct than you think. According to this [the compiler recognizer curly braces as angle brackets and binds them correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/11/750056.aspx).

Comment: I agree. C# is severely lacking in the documentation area, which is sad because (bias incoming) Java does it really well, and Java should not be doing anything better than C#! JavaDoc allows for HTML tags such as italics, bold, lists (yes I know C# docs can have lists but they're fugly in IntelliSense), hyperlinks, links to code within the project, images, and you can even use font style CSS to colour the text! I would much prefer to see the documentation in an easily-readable format in the IDE, rather than chasing it up online. It's a time-saver to be sure. MSFT need to up their game here!

Answer (score 12):

C# XML comments are written in XML, so you would use normal XML escaping.

For example...

```
<summary>Here is an escaped &lt;token&gt;</summary>
```

Comment: I forgot the ";"

Answer (score 5):

I've found a livable solution to this problem is simply including two examples: one difficult-to-read version in the XML comments w/ escape characters, and another readable version using conventional `//` comments.

Simple, but effective.

Answer (score 3):

Better than using {...} is using ≤...≥ (less than or equals sign, greater than or equals sign, U2264 and U2265 in Unicode).
Looks like underlined angle brackets but still definitely angle brackets! And only adds a couple of bytes to your code file.

Answer (score 3):

I like @Mick Bruno's idea of using similar looking characters to keep it legible in the code. Single guillemets work pretty well:

`List‹int›`

The Windows keyboard shortcuts are:

- Alt+0139
- Alt+0155

(where the numbers are typed on the keypad)

Comment: Readable in code file and in intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Even better try U2280 and U2281 - just copy and paste from [List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) (mathematical operators section).

Comment: Unicode operators are OK when they are used to represent actual mathematical operators, poor if they are used in code snippets that happen to be in a comment (e.g. `List<int>`). Think about e.g. copy-pasting the code snippet.

Comment: can you provide an example of how using this in a comment ? never used unicode characters indeed

Comment: Copy and paste the character as described above.