# How to add List type code example in XML comment?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I have used below XML comment,

```
    /// <example> 
    /// This example shows how to use <see cref="SampleCollection"/> property.
    /// <code>
    /// class TestClass 
    /// {
    ///      List<string> collection = new List<string>();
    ///      collection.Add("Column1");
    ///      collection.Add("Column2");
    ///      this.SampleCollection = collection;
    /// }
    /// </code>
    /// </example>        
    public List<string> SampleCollection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

But it has the following warning error,

> XML comment on 'SampleCollection' has badly formed XML -- 'End tag
>   'code' does not match the start tag 'string'.'

because List definition has the `<string>`. So it considered that as XML tag.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape characters in c# comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377372/how-do-i-escape-characters-in-c-sharp-comments)

Answer (score 7):

Use a [CDATA block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) to embed raw text within the XML:

```
<![CDATA[
List<string> ...
]]>
```

Comment: thanks. But still i have warning..Below is my modified code,
///      <![CDATA[
///      List <string> excludeColumns = new List<string>();
///      ]]]>
please let me know if i missed anything?