# Can I use quote marks in an XML documentation comment?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

When writing an XML documentation comment in a C# source file, do I need to replace `"` with `&quot;`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377372/how-do-i-escape-characters-in-c-sharp-comments) discusses *how* to replace characters, but does not establish *which* characters need replacing, aside from establishing that angle brackets do need replacing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Comment: Whether it's a duplicate or not is dependent on whether we can assert that the set of things you can do in a C# XML documentation comment is identical to the set of things you can do in an XML document. I decline to take a stance on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, just like normal XML, you only need to escape the quotes when they would otherwise have a special meaning. So if your XML documentation contains an attribute and you want a double quote in the attribute value, *then* you'd either use an attribute or use a single quote for the value start/end:

```
/// Foo <element attr="Bar&quot;Baz" />
/// Foo <element attr='Bar"Baz' />
```

But it's *very* rare to need attribute values with quotes in within XML documentation, in my experience. They're almost always references to parameters, members, or list types.