# How to show '<' char in C# XML comments?

Tags: c#, xml

I searched a lot, but couldn't find how to show '<' char in C# XML comments?

Comment: What do you mean by c# xml comments? In my world thats method and code commenting in .cs files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml string in a C# summary comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607094/xml-string-in-a-c-sharp-summary-comment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape characters in c# comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377372/how-do-i-escape-characters-in-c-sharp-comments)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Did you try the normal XML escaping of `&lt;` - that should work, I believe:

```
/// <summary>
/// Less than is &lt;
/// Greater than is &gt;
/// Ampersand is &amp;
/// </summary>
```

Basically it's normal XML.

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot @Jon.
You helped me a lot specially with this sentence:
"Basically it's normal XML."

Comment: Unless it's inside a generic typename, where you would use curly braces like `<see cref="List{string}" />`

Answer (score 17):

You need to escape it as in normal XML: with `&lt;`
Same goes for `&gt;` for >

Answer (score 14):

You can use HTML escape codes, as mentioned in other answers, but you could also look at using the CDATA - (Unparsed) Character Data tag, here is a link with more [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Cheers

Comment: This is very usefull when having html in a <code></code> block

Answer (score 10):

Would `&lt;` work?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As @Eris mentioned we could also use

```
<summary cref="C{T}">
```

instead of

```
<summary cref="C &lt; T &gt;">
```

for sake of delimiting a generic type

[See a nice example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx#code-snippet-4)